# bool value render asp-for for checkbox but it always get True value not false in mvc core razor view?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

```
      <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                 
                                
                                    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox style-0" asp-for="Approver" />
                                
                                    <span>Approval</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
```

Always get true value not false whenever check or not check checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,the usage of `<input type="radio" class="checkbox style-0" asp-for="Approver" />` in my view is wrong,because the value is null.
Here is a demo:

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
        {
            
            Genders g = new Genders();
            g.genders = new List<string> { "Male", "Female", "Unspecified" };
            
        
            return View(g);
        }
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Test(String gender) {
            return View();
        }
```

Genders:

```
public class Genders
    {
        public List<string> genders { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
<form method="post">
    
  
    @foreach(var gender in Model.genders){
    <div>
        <input type="radio" name="Gender" value="@gender" />@gender<br />
    </div>
    }

    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is radio option for only true false, so you can do it in simple way without iterating any collection.

```
<div>
     <input type="radio" name="check" value="1"> true<br />
     <input type="radio" name="check" value="0"> false<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use onchange javascript function if not able to bind value in model bool property.

```
<input asp-for="Approver" type="checkbox"  value="false"    
  onchange="this.value=this.checked" />
```